# when onsubmit event in form only first function is working i want to return all 3 function with true

Tags: javascript, ajax

## Ajax code to check email is new or existing

I want all the three function `return(checkpass() && check() && validate(this))` to work. Currently only the function `checkpass()` is working. If I write `return(check() && checkpass() && validate(this))`, only `check()` function gets triggered.

```js
function check(){
    var uname=document.forms["register_form"]["uname"].value;
    var uemail=document.forms["register_form"]["uemail"].value;
    var upassword=document.forms["register_form"]["upassword"].value;
    var ucpassword=document.forms["register_form"]["ucpassword"].value;

    if(uname=="" || uemail=="" || upassword=="" || ucpassword==""){
        alert("all fields must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
function checkpass(){
    var upass=document.forms["register_form"]["upassword"].value;
    var ucpass=document.forms["register_form"]["ucpassword"].value;
    if(upass!=ucpass){
        alert("Confirm password should be same as password");
        return false;
    }
    if(upass=="" && ucpass==""){
        alert("cannot be kept blank");
        return false;
    }
}
function validate(useremail){
    xhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET","emailvalidate.php?uemail="+useremail,true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhttp.responseText==""){
                document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="cannot be empty";
                return false;
            }
            else if(xhttp.responseText=="OK"){
                document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<span class='badge badge-pill badge-primary'>welcome new user</span>";
            }
            else if(xhttp.responseText=="NO"){
                document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<span class='badge badge-pill badge-primary'>Email Already Exist</span>";
                return false;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="error happened";
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="register_action.php" id="register_form" name="register_form" onsubmit="return (checkpass() && check() && validate(this));">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uname">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Enter Name " name="uname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uemail">Email id: </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="uemail" placeholder="Enter Email ID" name="uemail"
               onkeyup="javascript:validate(this.value)"><br>
        <span id="alert"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="upassword">Enter Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="upassword" placeholder="Set password" name="upassword">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ucpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ucpassword" placeholder="Enter password again" name="ucpassword" >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you call other functions inside the entry function?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific as to what you want. Do you want all three checks to *always* run (i.e. if there are multiple failures there will be more than one `alert()`)? Or, do you want the checks to run in order until one of them fails and then not run the others after that one? Which of those you want is going to determine how the code is written. An answer can't be supplied without knowing which of these you want.

Comment: Your primary issue is that you have no conditions under which any of your checks pass (i.e. return a `true` value).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap them in a function:

```
var wrapper = function(){
   return checkpass() && check() && validate(this);
}
```

and then

```html
<form onsubmit="javascript:wrapper()">
```

Also, you can curry this chain of functions to increase readability but well, the example above must resolve your problem.

Comment: Not working still the checkpass() function is validating and if i fill password and confirm password and leave name and email id blank the form gets submited with name and email id is seen blank in database.

Comment: Also I want to know whether my rest of  code is right?